# Swift - How do I update a label the Relative altitude change in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have managed to get this to print the Relative Altitude data to the log however what I would like to do is get it to print to a designated label.Any help would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var altitudeLabel: UILabel!
    let altimeter = CMAltimeter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

        if CMAltimeter.isRelativeAltitudeAvailable() {
            altimeter.startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler: { data, error in
                if (error == nil) {
                    println("relative Altitude: \(data.relativeAltitude)")
                    println("Pressure: \(data.pressure)")

                }
        })

    }

}

}
```

Comment: using `self.altitudeLabel.text` ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow if you are new iOS I think [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/DesigningaUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH6-SW1) is greate tutorial :)

Comment: Thanks @Raptor That worked perfect.  How would I change that to a Double Variable? Right now it outputs too many decimal points.

Comment: see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line to assign a float value with 2 decimal places to your `UILabel` outlet:

```
self.altitudeLabel.text = String(format: "%0.2f", data.relativeAltitude)
```

Comment: that is not outputting correctly it spits out 0.00 and doesn't update.  I guess I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this and it will due for now:

```
     var myIntValue:Int = Int(data.relativeAltitude)
                println ("My value is \(myIntValue)")
                self.altitudeLabel.text = ("\(myIntValue) M")
```